# Is it possible to visualize display using server launcher?

Tags: repast-simphony

I recently noticed that repast gives the possibility to use a server launcher. On [this](https://repast.github.io/docs/RepastNG/browser.html) manual is reported:

> New in Repast Simphony 2.7 is the ability to run your model using a web browser as the user interface. The browser-based GUI has the following features:
>
> - List item
>
>   2D grid, continuous space, and geography (GIS) visualization (currently restricted to edited styles only)
>
>   Tabbed and freeform visualization layout
>     Time series plot
>
>   Agent probing
>
>   Model parameter setting
>
>   Model runtime interaction (run, stop, pause, etc.)

I have tried so to launch my model using this mode. The problem is that the display is not visualized. In my display there is a Cotinuous space projection and a Network projection. 
Reading the quoted manual I thought that I cannot visualize the display because the framework has not already the feature which gives the possibility of plotting the network projection on the display using the browser-based GUI. Is this a possible reason?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that's exactly right. The network projection visualization has not been implemented in the alpha release of the browser-based GUI yet https://repast.github.io/docs/RepastNG/browser.html.